# Template optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++

I have the current function:

```cpp
template<const char A> constexpr void TypPrint() {
    switch (A) {
    case 'c':
        std::cout << "some" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 'd':
        std::cout << "out" << `std::endl;
        break;
    default:
    std::cout << "nothing" << std::endl;
    }
}

//call in main:
int main() {
    TypePrint<'g'>();
}
```

After inspecting the assembly it looks like it evaluates the input variable at runtime in switch.

I refactored the function to a:

```cpp
constexpr void Switch(char a) {
    switch (a) {
       case 'c':
          std::cout<<"some"<<std::endl;
          break;
       case 'd':
          std::cout<<"some"<<std::endl;
          break;
      default:
          std::cout<<"nothing"<<std::endl;
          break;
   }
}
//call Switch in type print.
```

I expected the compiler to optimize down the function into just a print statement or a single function calling the print considering its both a template and constexpression.
Is the functionality I want to achieve even possible with a switch?

Comment: What is `a` in the first snippet?

Comment: *After inspecting the assembly* It should be shown in the question.

Comment: That's a good question, 273K. We should consult *The Fonz*.

Comment: *I expected the compiler to optimize* Your expectation is wrong. `std::cout` makes your function non constexpr.

Comment: The a is a mistake, its supposed to be A.

Comment: *Is the functionality I want to achieve even possible with a switch?* How do you compile your first snippet, which compiler settings are set?

Comment: @273K ```/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\TemplateToying.pch" /diagnostics:column``` standard empty project settings visual studio

Comment: `constexpr` doesn't do what you think it does. `constexpr` tells the compiler that the _whole_ function may (for at least one set of inputs) be executed completely at compile-time. That's obviously not the case here, because you want your function to have runtime output that can't possibly be executed at compile-time. `constexpr` has nothing to do with what optimizations are possible inside the function.

Comment: If the compiler isn't optimizing the template to remove the `switch` check, then that's a quality-of-implementation issue of the compiler. There is nothing stopping it from doing that optimization, regardless of `constexpr`.

Comment: @user17732522 seems was a fault behind keyboard, rewrote the function just now, sat breakpoint at switch statement, got warning no switch exists.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible approaches:

```cpp
template<char A>
void Switch() {
    if constexpr (A == 'c') {
        std::cout << "some\n";
    }
    else if constexpr (A == 'd') {
        std::cout << "some\n";
    }
    // ...
}

// call like:
Switch<'c'>();
```

`if constexpr` ensures that there is no runtime overhead for branching, but the condition must be a constant expression.

Since you're using `std::cout <<` in each branch, you could also write a `consteval` function that picks the right constant for you:

```cpp
consteval const char* Switch(char a) {
    switch (a) {
    case 'c': return "some\n";
    case 'd': return "some\n";
    default: return "nothing\n";
    }
}

// call like:
std::cout << Switch('c');
```

Instead of a `consteval` function, you could also write a `constexpr` function and store the result of `Switch` in a `constexpr` variable. In either case, there would be no runtime overhead caused by the `switch`.

Comment: thank you, I guess I assumed in my code that the constexpr qualifies all the possible parts of the functions execution tree to compile time. But this clears up the fog, now that I think about it the documentation of constexpr states that it All parts of the function must should have the possibility to be evaluated at compiletime or it will be deferred to runtime. I understood it, wrongly so, to only mean the input variables and that constexpr qualification needed only to be inserted at the top level for that to happen. Thanks Alot!

Comment: At least in my view, the second approach you give is usually preferable. As often as situations like this occur, I'm tempted to suggest writing a `sparse_map` class that lets you load up values for a few specific keys, and returns a specified default for all other keys.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot yet comment, so I will anwear this here: Use consteval. This guarantees that a function is evaluated at compile time.

EDIT: Of course, for this to work you would have to drop std::cout, since it happens at runtime.

Comment: `consteval` will make the function uncallable.

Comment: *"This guarantees that a function is evaluated at compile time."*, or that the compiler will tell us that it cannot be evaluated at compile time. Producing output will have to be done at runtime.